# how to mock the if condition that checks the data in database with moq

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I am trying to mock a method that first checks if the data is present in database, if not then it calls the save method. How do i mock the if condition?

Code is like this

```
public MyCode AddMyCode(MyCode myCode)
        {
            int workingUnitId = _sessionManager.CurrentUser.WorkingUnit.Id;
            if (!_db.MyCodes.Any(d => d.Code == myCode.Code && d.UnitId == this.CurrentUserParentUnitId))
            {
                _db.MyCodes.Add(myCode);
                SaveMyCode();
                return myCode;
            }
            return myCode;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use interfaces to decouple database access code (EF here) and your business logic.
this way you can test your logic without need for a real database.

a good tutorial could be this : http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 1):

You can mock your data base call by `setting up some dummy data into MyCodes` and see whether the rest of the code is working fine.

**Updated:**

**include a static method like this:**

```
 public static Mock<ControllerContext> MockSession()
        {
            var controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
            controllerContext.Setup(X => X.HttpContext.Session["UserName"]).Returns("Avinash");
            return controllerContext;
        }
```

**Then you can do:**

```
In your test method,
```

Use the above static method to mock the session:

```
 target.ControllerContext = MockSession().Object;
```

This will mock the session. The above example is from `asp.net MVC Prespective`. I am not sure how to do it with normal webforms.

You can try to implement it for webforms also based on above.

Comment: MyCodes is a DbSet method in EfDbContext. So I should create a mock object for EFDbContext, then call the MyCodes method and then add dummy data to it?

Comment: I am getting an unhandled exception at this line-
int workingUnitId = _sessionManager.CurrentUser.WorkingUnit.Id;

Comment: You got to mock your sessions too..since you are not actually running the application rather you are just unit testing it.

Comment: @khan88..are you using MVC?

Comment: I created the mock and set it up like this- 
var _mockSessionMgr = new Mock<ISessionManager>();
_mockSessionMgr.SetupGet(x => x.Currentuser.WorkingUnit.Id).Returns(2);
Still getting the error as Invalid Set-up on non-virtual member

Comment: yes the code is written in MVC but i am not actually hitting the controllers while unit testing.

Comment: Thanks. I will implement and check

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50110/discussion-between-khan88-and-avinash-kothamasu)

Comment: @khan88..sorry ,I dont have access to chat. its blocked for me